# How to create a 2d probability density heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have x, y coordinates which I want to represent the 2d axis, and then the values for the plot I want to be a heatmap corresponding to probabilities for the respective x,y coordinates. Here's the sample data I have right now.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import pandas as pd

x = np.linspace(-1,1,200)
y = np.linspace(-1,1,200)
z = [random.uniform(0, 1) for val in range(200)]


df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x,'y':y,'z':z})
```

I want it to look something like this (obviously with different axes etc):

[image]

How would I do this?

Comment: What you've shown is different to the code: the graph shows the bucketed (albeit small buckets) frequencies of 2 different independently normally distributed variables (x and y). You are, for each x and y, producing a random, normally distributed z value. When graphed this will only look like noise. What exactly are you after?

Comment: a 2 dimensional box with a heatmap inside that corresponds to the z column values. values close to 1 should be very light and values close to 0 should be very dark. the box should range the coordinates of the x column on the x axis and range the coordinates of the y column on the y axis

Comment: I understand that, but do you want a distribution that looks like the image? Your data does not match that.

Comment: No it doesn't need to match the image. I just posted the image as an approximate example. I understand now what you mean that the image doesn't correspond to what my data represents.

Comment: Did you look at hist2d?  https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist2d.html https://matplotlib.org/stable/plot_types/stats/hist2d.html#sphx-glr-plot-types-stats-hist2d-py

Comment: hist2d would be the best way for bucketed problems (like in the example image where the graph displays frequencies of the buckets) but for generally showing a heatmap of any kind, see my answer below

Comment: Yes agreed, if they already have z.  The title is confusing...

Answer (score 0):

A simple example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
im = ax.imshow([[np.random.uniform(0, 1) for _ in range(100)] for _ in range(100)], extent=[-1, 1, -1, 1])
cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
```

[image: Simple random heatmap]

The idea is to have a 2d array of the intensities. This can be done in many ways, such as using histogram functions, or just providing noise as in the example. As in this simple case we know that the `x` and `y` values are uniformly spread, we don't have to supply these values, except for in the `extent=[..]` arg, containing the `x` and `y` ranges respectively.